# PyQt5 QDialog inside QApplication Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Bit of a quandary in selecting the proper method for what I need.  I have a PyQt5 application for which I need to pop up a QDialog (to show, say, progress):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QWidget, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class TestWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(TestWidget,self).__init__(*args)
        loadUi('test2.ui',self)

class ClientReports(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(ClientReports,self).__init__(*args)
        loadUi('clientreports.ui',self)
        self.subWindowCounter = 0
        testItem = QAction('&Test',self)
        testItem.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        testItem.setStatusTip('Test The New Process')
        testItem.triggered.connect(self.test_new_item)
        self.menubar.addAction(testItem)

    def test_new_item(self):
        tw = TestWidget(self)
        tw.exec()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = ClientReports()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is:  Using a QDialog widget allows the user to drag the window all over the screen, when in fact, I need to stay within the confines of the application.  Enter the QMdiSubMenu option - which remains in the confines of the application frame, but I cannot make it modal.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish creating a window that is modal but stays within the confines of the application frame?

clientreports.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>mainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="mainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1118</width>
    <height>730</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>PPS Client Custom Reports</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QMdiArea" name="mdiArea"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1118</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuReports">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Reports</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuReports"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

test2.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>114</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
     <property name="value">
      <number>24</number>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: With or without QMdiSubMenu the Dialog does not move with respect to the window, you could explain to me better your problem, maybe with images that illustrate your problem you could understand

Comment: I need the dialog to stay inside the application frame.  I also considered using QMidiSubWindow but I need the dialog to be modal.

Comment: in linux I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/FL6jI30

Comment: and I have tried to take the QDialog out of the window as it shows your image and I could not, that is to say it is still modal, consequently if I move the QDialog the main window also moves

Comment: Can you drag the dialog outside of the border of the main window?  If so this is what I am trying to avoid.  The image I posted was AFTER I dragged the dialog window outside of the main window.  I am using Linux Mint 19.

Comment: the images I have shown in the link shows my attempt to get the QDialog out of the main window but I could not, maybe it is a bug related to a version of PyQt5 or your OS, what version do you use of PyQt5 and what is your OS ?

Comment: OK, so I am confused.  You tried to drag the dialog box outside of the mainwindow?  I thought the dialog box was independent of the main window and could be dragged anywhere on the screen.  I am using Linux Mint 19 and PyQt5 5.10.1

Comment: if you pass a parent you can not because the position of the child is framed in the father, with your current code if you move the dialog will also move the main window, and the position of the dialogue with the window will always be the same. Do you want a window to move inside the QMdiArea as a QMdiSubWindow ?, if so, you must change the QDialog to QWidget in both the code and the design and you must QMdiSubWindow, confirm if the latter is what you want.

Comment: So the code I posted will move the Main window and the Dialog window if I try to drag the dialog window outside of the Main window?  I'm not seeing this behavior.  I can drag the main dialog box outside of the main window as you see in my graphic.  So this makes no sense to me.  I also explained that I could use the subwindow in the mdiArea of the mainwindow; however, it will not be modal - so I can't use that option either.  I've tried this code on both Linux and Windows and I get the same behavior.  So I am really confused at this point.

Comment: Well, I tried it with PyQt5 5.11.2 in arch linux

Comment: Just upgraded to 5.11.2 and I can still drag the popup dialog all over the screen.

Comment: @Elcid_91 All the behaviour you describe matches what I see using the openbox wm on arch linux (and it also seems quite weird to me that a modal dialog would move its parent window). I don't think there is any built-in way to constraint the moving/resizing of a dialog to its parent rect. You will probably have to override `resizeEvent` and update the geometry manually.

Comment: ekhumoro...thanks.  Going to write a custom QDialog that will check position on move and resize events to keep the dialog restrained in the main window.

Answer (score -1):

> Qt::FramelessWindowHint
>   Produces a borderless window. The user cannot move or resize a borderless window via the window system. On X11, the result of the flag is dependent on the window manager and its ability to understand Motif and/or NETWM hints. Most existing modern window managers can handle this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QWidget, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic       import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt


class TestWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(TestWidget,self).__init__(*args)
        loadUi('test2.ui',self)
        # +++
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

class ClientReports(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(ClientReports,self).__init__(*args)
        loadUi('clientreports.ui',self)
        self.subWindowCounter = 0
        testItem = QAction('&Test',self)
        testItem.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        testItem.setStatusTip('Test The New Process')
        testItem.triggered.connect(self.test_new_item)
        self.menubar.addAction(testItem)

    def test_new_item(self):
        tw = TestWidget(self)
        tw.exec()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = ClientReports()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks S.Nick but this is not what I am looking for.